# base64 encoded music file only playing 6 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, audio, base64

hello i have a process which is uploading a file in .mp3 format converting it to base64 then saving it in a database, when you pull the file (from the database) to play its only playing 6 seconds of this file? i cant seem to find out where i have gone wrong. 
i am only in the testing stages of this for a site i am creating but i want to get this right before i atually put the site out fully, i have set up the images which works perfect but the audio and video i am having major problems with.
this is the code to upload form

```
    <form action="action2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>" hidden="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

and this is the part to upload, store, encode and delete the file.

```
    <?php
    require 'assests/classes/init.php';

    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
     $allowedExts = array("mp3","wav","ogg");
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/x-mpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/x-mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/x-mpeg3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/x-mpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/x-mpegaudio")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wav")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/x-wav")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/ogg"))   
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000000000000000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1048576) . " MB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        echo (20000000 / 1024);
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          var_dump($_FILES);
          $byte_array = file_get_contents("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          $audio = base64_encode($byte_array);
          unlink('upload/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          $jk = new users;
          $jk->audio_upload($_POST['user_id'],$audio);
          echo $audio;
          var_dump($jk->audio_upload($_POST['user_id'],$audio));
          var_dump($audio);
          }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }

    var_dump($_FILES);
    var_dump($extension);
    ?>
```

then i use this to play it

```
    <?php
    $jk = new users;
    $audio = $jk->testing_audio_base_64($_SESSION['user_id']);
    var_dump($audio);
    ?>
    <audio controls >
   <?php echo '<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64, '.$audio.'" >'?>
     Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

but it only shows 6 seconds of the file? 
have i done something wrong here?

Comment: What have you done to analyze the problem? Have you verified that what you encoded to base64 is actually stored in the database? Have you verified that what is stored in the database actually appears in the data-URL? Have you verified that you do not exceed the size limit of data-URLs in your particular browser?

Comment: i have checked the file in the database and it uploads it correctly, i have checked that it is in the data-URL. The view soruce shows
<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64, then all the text of the base64, but when i click on it in the browser i just get data:  thats all?

Answer (score 0):

Certain browsers limit the size of a data url, e.g. [IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> Data URIs cannot be larger than 32,768 characters.

or [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs#Common_problems)

> Although Mozilla supports data URIs of essentially unlimited length, browsers are not required to support any particular maximum length of data. For example, the Opera 11 browser limits data URIs to around 65000 characters.

Another issue could be PHP max post/upload size or memory limit.

Comment: If max post/upload size is exceeded, `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` would indicate an error. If the memory limit is exceeded, a fatal error occurrs.

Comment: it uploads properly and it also store in the database correctly it is only playing 6 seconds of this file? could it be to do with the audio controls i have on?

Comment: Consult the documentation of the browser that you are using, to determine what the effects of the `controls` attribute in your browser are.

Answer (score 0):

i had saved it as a txt not a longblob so it wasnt working proper the fix was changeing the type from txt to long blob